# SQL Query join issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using SQL Server 2005.

I'm having some issues when executing this query.

My code is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get]           
  @ApplicantID  int            

AS                      
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        isnull(M_EvalApplicationStatuses.EvalApplicationStatus,'')        EvalApplicationStatus,
        isnull(M_Users.CompletionMailSent,'') MailSent,
        isnull(APP_Applications.FirstName,'') FirstName,
        isnull(APP_Applications.LastName,'') LastName,
        isnull(M_Users.UserName,'') UserName,
        isnull(APP_Applications.DocTrackingGenComment,'') DocTrackingGenComment

FROM
        APP_Applications
    left outer join
        M_Users
    ON
        APP_Applications.UserID = M_Users.UserID                        
    left outer join
        M_EvalApplicationStatuses
    ON
        APP_Applications.Status = M_EvalApplicationStatuses.EvalApplicationStatusID and M_EvalApplicationStatuses.Status = 1                    

WHERE
        ApplicantID =@ApplicantID
END
```

This now works perfectly. But I want to get data from another table, so I just left join that table to this query. Here I have found the issue. My new table name is `[APP_DocumentTracking]` and the below query I used to retrieve data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.Date,'') Date,
    isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.IntervTime,'') IntervTime,
    isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.Telephoneinterview,'') Telephoneinterview
FROM [APP_DocumentTracking] 
where APP_DocumentTracking.ApplicantID = @ApplicantID
```

These two queries are separately working fine... but I want to join these two queries and the result will be get in one table. How can I do this? plz help me

Comment: Do you get multiple result set for the SP?

Comment: "here I have found the issue", what is the issue you found?

Comment: i don't know how to join this 2 tables

Comment: Is there relation between those two tables? i guess there is no relation defind, so you are finding it difficult. in this case, i am seeing ApplicantID in both tables try to join using this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment in sarathkumar's answer the problem is Ambiguous column name 'ApplicantID'. Try the below for that problem. I have updated the `where clause` from your comment.

```
left outer join [APP_DocumentTracking] on [APP_DocumentTracking].ApplicantID=APP_Applications.ApplicantID 
WHERE [APP_DocumentTracking].ApplicantID =@ApplicantID END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join as a subquery with first and second one .Please update the structure  in SqlFiddle or here Itself.Then it will be easy to give u the answer...

Here is the code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get]           
  @ApplicantID  int            

AS                      
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        isnull(M_EvalApplicationStatuses.EvalApplicationStatus,'')        EvalApplicationStatus,
        isnull(M_Users.CompletionMailSent,'') MailSent,
        isnull(APP_Applications.FirstName,'') FirstName,
        isnull(APP_Applications.LastName,'') LastName,
        isnull(M_Users.UserName,'') UserName,
        isnull(APP_Applications.DocTrackingGenComment,'') DocTrackingGenComment 
        ,Trace.*

FROM
        APP_Applications
    left outer join
        M_Users
    ON
        APP_Applications.UserID = M_Users.UserID                        
    left outer join
        M_EvalApplicationStatuses
    ON
        APP_Applications.Status = M_EvalApplicationStatuses.EvalApplicationStatusID and M_EvalApplicationStatuses.Status = 1                    


LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT DISTINCT 
    isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.Date,'') Date,
    isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.IntervTime,'') IntervTime,
    isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.Telephoneinterview,'') Telephoneinterview
 FROM [APP_DocumentTracking] 
 where APP_DocumentTracking.ApplicantID = @ApplicantID
) AS Trace 

ON APP_Applications.ApplicantID = Trace.ApplicantID

WHERE APP_Applications.ApplicantID =@ApplicantID  

END
```

Cheers.

Comment: ApplicantID is the primery key in APP_Applications table,and ApplicantID is also in APP_DocumentTracking,here it is the foreign key.

Comment: i just leftjoin the the first queries result with APP_DocumentTracking table,but using leftjoin i am writing APP_DocumentTracking .ApplicantID=APP_Applications .ApplicantID.But the same ApplicantID comparison is used in where condition...

Comment: left outer join
 [APP_DocumentTracking] on [APP_DocumentTracking].ApplicantID=APP_Applications.ApplicantID
WHERE
  ApplicantID =@ApplicantID
END

Comment: the issue i found is Ambiguous column name 'ApplicantID'.

Comment: for checkingapplicantid is the only common field

Comment: Use Alias Name and represent ApplicationID... It will avoid Confusion over query...

Comment: If u can do by Joining also but Distinct Date wont work when u go for join.. For That only i told u go with SubQuery then Join that ... It wont affect ur desired previous result set..

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get]           
  @ApplicantID  int            

AS                      
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        isnull(M_EvalApplicationStatuses.EvalApplicationStatus,'')        EvalApplicationStatus,
        isnull(M_Users.CompletionMailSent,'') MailSent,
        isnull(APP_Applications.FirstName,'') FirstName,
        isnull(APP_Applications.LastName,'') LastName,
        isnull(M_Users.UserName,'') UserName,
        isnull(APP_Applications.DocTrackingGenComment,'') DocTrackingGenComment

FROM APP_Applications
    left outer join M_Users
    ON APP_Applications.UserID = M_Users.UserID                        
    left outer join
        M_EvalApplicationStatuses
    ON
        APP_Applications.Status = M_EvalApplicationStatuses.EvalApplicationStatusID and M_EvalApplicationStatuses.Status = 1

    left join
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.Date,'') Date,
            isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.IntervTime,'') IntervTime,
            isnull(APP_DocumentTracking.Telephoneinterview,'') Telephoneinterview
            APP_DocumentTracking.ApplicantID
        FROM [APP_DocumentTracking] 
        where APP_DocumentTracking.ApplicantID = @ApplicantID
        ) AliasSubquery
        on 1=1

WHERE
        ApplicantID =@ApplicantID
END
```